# how can I make upperline upon a letter in MS-word

Tags: microsoft-word

how can I make `upperline` upon a letter in MS-word that is somthing like `bar`.

Comment: Is this programming related?

Comment: You should accept answers to your questions by clicking the hollow check.

Answer (score 2):

[Like this](http://word.tips.net/Pages/T000268_Overlining_Characters.html).

Comment: very cool solution!